# PyQT Open another window from a button

Tags: python, pyqt, qt-designer

I am trying to open another window:

```
import FrmGuardar
forma = FrmGuardar 
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.actionPrimer_Formulario, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("triggered()")), OpenWindow)
```

The function I am using is:

```
def OpenWindow():
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    FrmGuardar = QtGui.QWidget()
    ui = forma.Ui_FrmGuardar()
    ui.setupUi(FrmGuardar)
    FrmGuardar.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The window appears, but then disappears instantly. I require assistance in solving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the OpenWindow function you have

```
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

which is ending the code, and i don't think you should be making a new app per window.

Comment: The same problem if I remove
    sys.exit(app.exec_())